# SharePoint 2007 Publishing Site

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Created a new Publishing site to serve a portal for our division. It contains several custom coded webparts that fetch data from the db and/or RSS feds and outside links.

I found it absolutely dumb that as a owner I'm having to approve my own page. Is there was to turn off this functionality? Or modifying so that only a document library runs through the approval process?

In the edit mode, there is a link "Reminder: Check for Unpublished Items" and if I click it all of my web parts and all the links, pictures, and other contents within these web parts are highlighted with a fat dotted red line. How do I get rid of this since what sharepoint is complaining about is embedded in these webpart?

If I try to create a doc library called "Announcements" I get an error:

"The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Announcements/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

For some reason it does not like the word, as I can call it BuggsBunny and all is fine. Is "Announcements" a key word of some kind in SharePoint? I really need to create a list with this name.

Thanks,

Risho

Answer (score 1):

> I found it absolutely dumb that as a
>   owner I'm having to approve my own
>   page. Is there was to turn off this
>   functionality? Or modifying so that
>   only a document library runs through
>   the approval process?

You should choose, when you are creating your site, a "Publishing site" template rather than a "Publishing site with workflows". The main difference between these two is the fact that you'll approval workflow on nearly everything activated with the later while the former is free of it but still allows you to activate it if needed

> there is a link "Reminder: Check for
>   Unpublished Items" and if I click it
>   all of my web parts and all the links,
>   pictures, and other contents within
>   these web parts are highlighted with a
>   fat dotted red line. How do I get rid
>   of this since what sharepoint is
>   complaining about is embedded in these
>   webpart?

Don't know where you are hosting your webpart ressources (style library, document library, image library ? outside of SharePoint ? On the 12 hives ?) but if they are within SharePoint libraries and the content is not published with a 1.0 version available for the readers, you'll have this error. Deactivate the approval workflow or publish AND approve theses items. Please also note that external content will probably trigger this red link, but I suggest you to use a limited "visitor" account to check up the final rendering. The "outlining" is a nice addition but it's not always working as expected, mainly with external content.

> If I try to create a doc library
>   called "Announcements" I get an error:
>   "The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that
>   it is spelled correctly.

There is a default annoucement list in SharePoint (with its dedicated template, not sure that you have one provisioned with the publishing template that you picked, that might be a reason why you have this strange error. The default announcements list or its template is not a document library. If you want a document library with that name, and that specific name gives you that error, I suggest that you create a document library called AnnouncementsDocuments and then change its title for "Annoucements", that way the url will be clean of the dreaded name and you'll have the specified title.

For the error message, have a look within the source of the error message page, you might have, in some comments, more information that might help us to help you.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thank you for your post. This give enough to continue. Interestingly, under the Publishing tab I only get two options: Collaboration Portal and Publishing Portal, so how do you chose one without the workflow?

Comment: Alright, I figured out how to turn off workflow but there is one issue I've overlooked. I have the announcements web part that I need to have approval process in place so that we can monitor what is published. Is there way to create a custom work flow just for this part? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this is the "collaboration portal" the one you need to pick. and for your second question, do you want to see what has been published recently or do you want to see what are the pending submissions ? How is the annoucements list related ? People are adding items into that one ?

Comment: Thanks for comming back, this is a publishing portal since there is really no document sharring. It's basically a web front end with a web part that points to this document library. In there people can post word docs/pdfs for others to see but not before they are approved by managers. So until docs are approved they cannot be displayed. ---- I started from scratch, a brand new publishig portal with the blue theme and picture of happy people....       In the press release page I added a document webpart. When I added a document, it was immdiatelly visible to all. So I'm not sure about this.